# How to correctly update TabBarItem's badge value?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, uitabbarcontroller, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a three `tableViewController` and they’re managed by the `tabBarController`. And each `tabBarItem` must be alerted about overdue items like any others apps. In my first `tableViewController` I’ve tried to show overdue items count inside of the `tabBarItem`’s `badgeValue`. These values are comes from the `fetchedResultsController`’s `fetchedObjects.count`, it well working condition.

```
func tabBarBadgeUpdater() {

    for viewController in (self.tabBarController?.viewControllers)! {

        let overdue = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.filter({ (record) -> Bool in
            return (record.date?.compare(Date()) != .orderedDescending)
        })

        print(overdue!.count)

        if viewController.tabBarItem.tag == 1 {

            if overdue!.count != 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = "\(overdue!.count)"
                    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = ""
                    viewController.tabBarItem.badgeColor = .clear
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my problem line is deleting them. When I tried to delete last object from the model and it’s still shows value 1.

[image: Before deleting]

[image: After deleted]

How to correctly show `TabBarItem`'s `badgeValue` ?

Comment: Does it even reach the code where you set it to "" ?  Another option could be to implement `controllerDidChangeContent` whenever your model changes, and then get the count from your `fetchedResultsController` and set your badge to that number.

Comment: When I added a new value to the model and then disappeared. But again and again the same result I'll get

Comment: Did you try a breakpoint at `viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = ""` ? Setting the badgeValue to `nil` instead of `""`works in my project.

Comment: Maybe my problem line is reloading data. If I have a last object in my firstVC and I tried to delete it from the model. After successfully deleted I'm received a message from the console like so:  " 1 " .  That means I have an overdue object. And I'm going to secondVC and then go back to firstVC, this my firstVC's viewDidAppear method will be called and firstVC becomes reloaded tableView. As well as badge is disappeared. In the console " 0 ".

Comment: @Koen Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try `controllerDidChangeContent` as suggested above? This way you don't have to worry about where to put your badge code; it will only change if your model changes.

Comment: Not yet! I should call this function after beginUpdates() ?

Comment: @Koen That's right! Thanks for your help. Happy coding. Works great as expected

Comment: Don't call it yourself, just implement it. Just make sure the the `viewController` is a delegate of the `fetchedResultsController`.

Comment: @Koen How it's done?

Comment: Great, I will put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you implement `controllerDidChangeContent` which is a delegate method of your `fetchedResultsController`. Everytime your model changes this will be called, and you can query the count and update your badge number.

Comment: `func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        self.tabBarBadgeUpdater()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }`  And works well! It's solved my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To clear mine, I just set the badgeValue to nil, not "":

```
tabController.tabBar.items[0].badgeValue = nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your support and answer! I don't know where I should call my function? Inside of the viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear? But both methods are does nothing in the runtime. Therefore I called this function both cellForRowAt indexPath and viewDidAppear. Perhaps my problem is reloading data? Again thank you

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found a Swift 5 solution to setting the tabBar item when you want to be able to move your tabBar Items around and it doesn't just mark the badge of a fixed tabBar item position.
Here is my solution that works wherever your UiView is placed in the tabBar:

```
// set badge value on your own nav controller

self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.badgeValue = scoreBoxLabelOutlet.text

// Then use a nil value to remove the Badge Item.
self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil
```

Where I used an outlet called scoreBoxLabelOutlet.text to collect the information.